# How to update one array that depends on another in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a search field and I want to filter users based on it.
I show users if there is no filter or `filteredUsers` if you search anything.

The issue is that if you search in the search bar and after that I'm trying to edit a field (inline edit), `users` is updated, but `filteredUsers` is not.

I have also other filters and actions, that's why I've posted only that part of the code. I have to use both of them because in other cases I need users.

How should this work in `vue.js`?

```js
//in componnet 
computed: {
      ...mapGetters([
        'users',
        'filteredUsers'
      ]),
      getFilteredUsers () {
        return this.filteredUsers || this.users
      }
    }

// in mutation
   UPDATE_CONSUMER (state, { user, index }) {
       // here users is updated, but filteredUsers in not
        state.users.splice(index, 1, user)
  },
```

```html
<tr v-for="user, index in getFilteredUsers">
```

```js
// getters.js file
export default {
  users: state => {
    return state.users
  },
  filteredUsers: state => {
    return state.filteredUsers
  }
}
```

```js
// mutations.js
SEARCH_USERS (state) {
    const searchTextTrimmed = state.searchText.trimStart()

    const users = [
      ...state.users.filter(user => {
        return user.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchTextTrimmed.toLowerCase())
      })
    ]
    if (searchTextTrimmed) {
      state.filteredUser = users
    } else {
      state.users = users
      state.filteredUser = null
    }
  }
```

Comment: A wild guess here is that `user` is an object that you get from `state`, and you edited the `user` object in place. Try make a deep copy of `user`. `state.users.splice(index, 1, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)))`

Comment: It would be great if you could provide your `filteredUsers` and `users` getters, along with you input field and its input handlers. So we can find more precisely where is the problem is hiding?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Your `filteredUsers as data` should be generate in `getters` and it's not necessary save it as state, because if you want use the current state of data u could do it without use his getter, then to use on the .vue file just will be `...mapState` equals to use `...mapGetters`. Only if you want apply some filter on your state there u should use his custom getter.

Comment: I updated my question again. I set `state.filterUsers` in `mutation` because this happens when user is searching and cannot move it to getters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you wouldn't have both arrays in the `state`. Instead you'd just have `users` and `searchText`. You'd then have `filteredUsers` in the `getters`, derived from `users` and `searchText`.

In the example below I've tried to preserve the `UPDATE_CONSUMER` mutation from the question. I extrapolated from there to assume that you want to create copies of the user objects when they are edited rather than mutating the original objects. The whole question becomes a bit moot if mutating the original objects is an option as the objects are shared between the two lists.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    searchText: '',
    
    users: [
      {name: 'Black', fruit: 'Apple'},
      {name: 'Blue', fruit: 'Pear'},
      {name: 'Brown', fruit: 'Banana'}
    ]
  },
  
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_CONSUMER (state, { user, index }) {
      state.users.splice(index, 1, user)
    },

    UPDATE_SEARCH_TEXT (state, searchText) {
      state.searchText = searchText
    }
  },
  
  getters: {
    filteredUsers (state) {
      const searchText = state.searchText.trimStart().toLowerCase()
      const users = state.users
      
      if (!searchText) {
        return users
      }

      return users.filter(user => user.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchText))
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapState(['users']),
    ...Vuex.mapGetters(['filteredUsers']),
    searchText: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.searchText
      },
      set (searchText) {
        this.$store.commit('UPDATE_SEARCH_TEXT', searchText)
      }
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    onInputFruit (user, fruit) {
      const newUser = {...user, fruit}
      const index = this.users.indexOf(user)
      
      this.$store.commit('UPDATE_CONSUMER', {user: newUser, index})
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app > * {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="searchText">
  <table>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Fruit</th><tr>
    <tr v-for="user in filteredUsers" :key="user.name">
      <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <input :value="user.fruit" @input="onInputFruit(user, $event.target.value)">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>{{ filteredUsers }}</p>
  <p>{{ users }}</p>
</div>
```

Some other points to note:

1. I've got rid of the getter for `users` and used `mapState` instead. If you'd rather do everything via `mapGetters` you could put that back the way it was.
2. You shouldn't need `getFilteredUsers`. Instead just have `filteredUsers` always return the current list of users matching the search criteria. I've included an optimisation to return early if there is no `searchText` but it would still work without it.
3. In your code you have `const users = [...state.users.filter`. There's no need to use `[...]` to create a new array here as `filter` will be returning a new array anyway.
4. I've kept the `searchText` and filtering in the store but that feels a bit like it should be handled by component state instead. It's difficult to say without knowing a lot more about your application but the search box is likely to be local to a small portion of the UI and that doesn't necessarily need to be shared with the rest of the application via the store.

A potential problem with the way I've implemented this is that the data is updated immediately as the user types. It isn't a problem in my example but if the list is filtered based on the field being edited that could cause that row to suddenly disappear as the user is typing. One way to avoid that problem is to wait for the field to blur before updating the data, e.g. using the `change` event instead of the `input` event. Other workarounds are available depending on precisely what the expected behaviour should be.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't get it how to use v-model set and get methods. I have seen an error in the console that it needs setter.

Comment: I get this error: `unknown mutation type: `UPDATE_SEARCH_TEXT` when I'm trying to use `commit` in the setter. My store contains modules and `users` mutation is inside `users` namespace. Maybe that's the issue. I tried with `        this.$store.commit('UPDATE_SEARCH_TEXT', searchText, {root; true})` but it's the same

Comment: @mistery_girl If you're using namespaced modules and you've added the `UPDATE_SEARCH_TEXT` mutation to your `users` module then it'd be `this.$store.commit('users/UPDATE_SEARCH_TEXT', searchText)`.

Comment: Thank you! I've just figured it out. I had to use
 `searchText: {
        get () {
          return this.$store.state.users.searchText
        },
        set (value) {
          this.$store.commit('users/UPDATE_SEARCH_TEXT', value)
        }
      }`

Comment: I see this error in the console when I'm typing in one of the fields:
`app.js:38875 [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."